# Python: Appending dictionary to JSON list:

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I would like to create a list of dictionaries in my JSON file. The problem, though, is that JSON does not append new data properly. Here is my code:

```
import json

json_data = [
    {
    'name': 'Luke',
    'age': 27
    },
    {
    'name': 'Harry',
    'age': 32
    },
    ]
with open('data.json', 'a+') as file:
    json.dump(json_data, file)
```

JSON just creates another whole list at each appending attempt:

```
[
    {"name": "Luke", "age": 27}, 
    {"name": "Harry", "age": 32}
][
    {"name": "Luke", "age": 27}, 
    {"name": "Harry", "age": 32}
][
    {"name": "Luke", "age": 27}, 
    {"name": "Harry", "age": 32}
]
```

I want to have one single list that holds all these dictionaries. Here's an example of how it SHOULD be like ideally:

```
[
    {"name": "Luke", "age": 27}, 
    {"name": "Harry", "age": 32},
    {"name": "Luke", "age": 27}, 
    {"name": "Harry", "age": 32},
    {"name": "Luke", "age": 27}, 
    {"name": "Harry", "age": 32},
]
```

How do I create something like that?
Thank you for all your help! :)

Comment: You'll have to read your list of dictionaries from the file, merge the read list with the new list, and write the result to a file (not in append mode).

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix solution with `eval()`:

```
import json

json_data = [
    {
    'name': 'Luke',
    'age': 27
    },
    {
    'name': 'Harry',
    'age': 32
    },
    ]

with open('data.json', 'r+') as file:  # read and append
    stored_info = eval(file.readline())  # using eval() to convert list in file to an actual list
    for i in stored_info:
        json_data.append(i)
    file.seek(0)  # clear file
    json.dump(json_data, file)
```

However, this will only work if `data.json` exists and already contains information. You might have to check if `data.json` exists(which means there will already be information if only program edits `data.json`):

```
...
try: 
    with open('data.json', 'r+') as file:  # read and append
        stored_info = eval(file.readline())  # using eval() to convert list in file to an actual list
        for i in stored_info:
            json_data.append(i)
        file.seek(0)  # clear file
        json.dump(json_data, file)
except:  # data.json doesn't exist
    with open('data.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(json_data, file)
```

Comment: I tried this one. For some reason, it gives me this error:
```File "<string>", line 0
     
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing```

Comment: @Hassan if `data.json` currently contains `[{"name": "Luke", "age": 27},  {"name": "Harry", "age": 32}][ {"name": "Luke", "age": 27}, {"name": "Harry", "age": 32}][ {"name": "Luke", "age": 27}, {"name": "Harry", "age": 32}]` or something of the sort you should delete it and rerun the code above, as eval() will return an error while reading it.